# How do I create a single large dictionary rather than a bunch a off little ones

Tags: python, pointers, dictionary, nested-loops

I am having an issue. The solution might be straight forward but i am not seeing it. The code below returns a bunch of individual dictionaries as opposed to one large dictionary. I then iterate through these small dictionaries to pull out values.  The problem is that I would much rather sort through one LARGE dictionary as opposed to a bunch of small ones. "objFunctions.getAttributes" returns a dictionary. "objFunctions.getRelationships" returns a pointer.

This is the output:
    {1:value}
    {2:value}
    {3:value}

This is what i want:
    {1:value,2:value,3:value}

```
for object in objList:
   relationship = objFunctions.getRelationships(object)
   for relPtr in relationships:
      uglyDict = objFunctions.getAttributes(relPtr)
```

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`.update()` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) to merge dicts:

```
attributes = {}
for object in objList:
    relationship = objFunctions.getRelationships(object)
    for relPtr in relationships:
        attributes.update(objFunctions.getAttributes(relPtr))
```

Note that if a key is repeated across different invocations of `.getAttributes` that the value stored in `attributes` in the end will be the last one returned for that key.

If you don't mind that your values are stored as lists; you'll have to merge your dicts manually with the values appended one by one to a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

attributes = defaultdict(list)
for object in objList:
    relationship = objFunctions.getRelationships(object)
    for relPtr in relationships:
        for key, value in objFunctions.getAttributes(relPtr):
            attributes[key].append(value)
```

Now your `attributes` dict will contain a list for each key, with the various values collected together. You could use a set as well, use `defaultdict(set)` and `attributes[key].add(value)` instead.

Comment: right. and there are duplicate keys and the values for those duplicate keys are different. i need them all

Comment: you're right. obvious solution. I guess I will have to keep iterating through those tiny dictionaries. I feel like there is a better way i can do this. Thankyou

Comment: I've updated and added some alternatives, where values are collected in a list or a set instead of overwriting the previous key.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> x = defaultdict(list)
>>> y = defaultdict(list)
>>> x[1].append("value1")
>>> x[2].append("value2")
>>> y[1].append("value3")
>>> y[2].append("value4")
>>> for k in y:
...     x[k].extend(y[k])
...
>>> print x
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['value1', 'value3'], 2: ['value2', 'value4']})
```